# Flutter method channel & Facebook AppEventLogger

Tags: android, facebook, flutter

I am trying to call a function from flutter on onTap event and pass some arguments into native android. Please note that I am more of a PHP/JavaScript developer, I am Kotlin virgin.

So far I have managed to do this using:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('foo.bar/example');

void _onTap() {
   var arguments = {'name': widget.recipe.name, 'id': widget.recipe.id.toString()};
   platform.invokeMethod('setPageView', arguments);
}
```

Then in the MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
private val channel: String = "foo.bar/example"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

    val logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this)


    MethodChannel(flutterView, channel).setMethodCallHandler(MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler(fun(methodCall: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        if (methodCall.method.equals("setPageView")) {
            val params = Bundle()

            params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT_TYPE, "recipe")
            params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT, methodCall.argument("recipe"))
            params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT_ID, methodCall.argument("id"))

            logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_VIEWED_CONTENT, 0.0, params)

            logger.logEvent("pageView", 0.0, params)

            System.out.println("Called setPageView.")

        }
    }))
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I log inside the MethodCallHandler the event is not sent to facebook for some reason. But if I log something right below the

```
val logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this)
```

The event is successfully sent to facebook.

The code inside the MethodCallHandler executes, so that´s not the problem.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making the content of MethodCallHandler as a standalone method in the MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val channel: String = "foo.bar/example"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

        MethodChannel(flutterView, channel).setMethodCallHandler(
                MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler(
                        fun(methodCall: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
                            if (methodCall.method.equals("setPageView")) {
                                logPageView(methodCall.argument("name"), methodCall.argument("id"))
                            }
                        }
                )
        )
    }

    fun logPageView(name: String?, id: String?) {
        val logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this)
        val params = Bundle()

        params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT_TYPE, "recipe")
        params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT, name)
        params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CONTENT_ID, id)
        params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CURRENCY, "EUR")

        logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_VIEWED_CONTENT, 0.0, params)
    }
}
```